# PHP active write to DIV with arrays

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Once again I'm posting for something that I've never dealt with or have not found the answers with my google searches.

I have a web app, that I want to turn on a "logging" section.

I want an empty DIV to have data written to it (they're array CURL requests and json responses).

I have found how to Jquery write to a div, but this doesn't work with arrays. Does anyone have a better suggestion for me?

Code:

```
<script>
 function updateProgress(progress){
    $("#progress").append("<div class='progress'>" + progress + "</div>");
 }
</script>


<div id='progress'></div>
```

in PHP:

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>parent.updateProgress('$response');</script>";
```

Error:  Array to string conversion

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried or set up a jsfiddle so that we can help you. jQuery is capable of parsing arrays and displaying the data and works well with JSON. Use AJAX to retrieve the data, then parse the data and append to the div.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Had to swap computers to add code, added above.

Comment: So, I'm guessing the `$response` PHP variable is an array? Can you do a var_dump on it to show what kind of array?

Comment: I just created an example of parsing the JSON for you here - http://jsfiddle.net/5HX4g/ Use AJAX to call the PHP and return the array to the JavaScript for parsing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZASU7/ sample array, they're all going to be different multi-dementional arrays. But I want to display them in JSON format in the div, which I can do fine with json_encode and <pre> tags. It's just the passing through to javascript and back to the div that I'm confused about.

Answer (score 0):

use `.html()` to write in to div

```
<script>
function updateProgress(progress) {
    $("#progress").html("<div class='progress'>" + progress + "</div>");
}
</script>
```

PHP:

```
echo "<script>";
echo "$(document).ready(function() {";
echo "updateProgress(" . $response. ");";
echo "});";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: I get [object Object] as a response instead of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The way you call this function `parent.updateProgress('$response');` is wrong, you need not remove `parent` from invoking statement something like this.

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>updateProgress('".$response."');</script>";
//-----------remove parent from here^
```

Now this function `updateProgress` will be invoked successfully.

If `$response` is an array, and you want to display this as string then you can use it.

```
$response =  implode(", ", $response);
echo "<script language='javascript'>updateProgress('".$response."');</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside your PHP code. The variable `$response` is an array and you're attempting to convert it to (cast it as) a string, hence the error, "Array to string conversion".

Basically, you're doing this:

```
echo (string)array('value1', 'value2'); // Notice: Array to string conversion
```

If this is just a basic array (as the above example is), you can easily fix this by using [implode](https://www.php.net/function.implode). For example:

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>parent.updateProgress('" . str_replace("'", '&#39;', implode(', ', $response)) . "');</script>";
```

If it's more complex (multi-dimensional array), you'll need to do some further processing to get only the values you want to show on the page.

Comment: So for this purpose I want to keep the JSON formatting, and it will contain multi-multi-multi-dimensional arrays :( Beset advice for that?

Comment: Use json_encode, instead of the implode, that'll change it from an array into a JSON string you can use. Also, remove all of the single quotes, as a JSON object should be passed directly into your function. You'll have to do _some_ sort of processing on the JS side though to make it into a string that can be written to HTML, otherwise you'll get "object" when the JSON object is cast as a string.

Comment: Ahh, just read your other comment - keep the single quotes and the str_replace when doing json_encode, since you want to show the raw JSON on the page.

Comment: how do i parse the json back to html? I've gotten the Object to work by writing it back to Object, but I honestly don't know Javascript so I'm trying to learn on the fly :(

Comment: Remove the quotes, and then inside your JavaScript function you can do something like `progress.loginAccounts[0].name`. Or that's what it looks like from your var_dump. If that doesn't work, show the json string that was returned.

Comment: sadly it's not always going to be loginAccounts[0]. sometimes the first array value changes, and sometimes there's multiple arrays at that level. hmmph.

Comment: so I probably need a catch all that does a forloop in javascript to rebuild the array to send back to html, but as I said before. I don't know javascript, but I'm open to learn if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Although after an alert test, javascript is getting [object Object] as a variable instead of the json_encoded string.

Comment: Check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). JS is just type-casting the array as a string. Use console.log to see the value of a variable (use Firebug or browser developer tools).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer Justin, I will check this out and see if it gets me in the right place.

Comment: Hey Justin, I looked at MDN. I still don't see how to pass the variable to Javascript function, I see the foreach to get the values once the array is there defined on MDN.